# Swing removing Gameobjects

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, collections

for my game i need to remove objects from my Panel. I want to store Square Objects in an ArrayList and remove them if mouse is klicked with an iterator.
But the three squares aren't painted to the panel. Has anyone an idea why they arent't painted?

Best Regards.

```
 public class Test {

 JFrame f = new JFrame();       
 JPanel panel =new JPanel();
 ArrayList<Square> list = new ArrayList<Square>();

public Test() {
    f.setSize(300,300); 
    f.addMouseListener(new Mouseklick());                      
    panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 
    f.add(p);     
                     // adding square to list and panel
    Square a = new Square(20, 20); list.add(a); panel.add(a) ;         
    Square b = new Square(40, 40); list.add(a); panel.add(b);
    Square c = new Square(60, 60); list.add(a); panel.add(c);

    panel.repaint();
    f.setVisible(true);     
}   

 class Square extends JLabel {          

public Square(int x , int y) { // Coordinates
    setBounds(x, y, 20,20);         
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    }       
}

class Mouseklick extends MouseAdapter {

   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {                                 
        Iterator<Square> iter = list.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Square q = iter.next();
            if( q.getX()==20){ // remove square with x Coord=20
                iter.remove();
                panel.repaint();
            }
        }           
   }
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {      
    new Test();             
 }
```

}

Comment: Your `JPanel` is under the control of a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) which is making decisions about the placement and sizing of your components, since you've not provided appropriate sizing hints, the labels are been sized to their default size of `0x0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JPanel` is under the control of a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) which is making decisions about the placement and sizing of your components, since you've not provided appropriate sizing hints, the labels are been sized to their default size of `0x0`

Also, you're only adding `a` to the panel...

```
Square a = new Square(20, 20); 
list.add(a); 
panel.add(a) ;         
Square b = new Square(40, 40); 
list.add(a);
panel.add(b);
Square c = new Square(60, 60); 
list.add(a); 
panel.add(c);
```

And since a component can only reside on single container, you actually only have a single component added to the container anyway.

Since layout management is some what complex, a better solution would be to follow a fully custom painted route.

That is, make use of the available geometry classes and paint them directly to the `JPanel` itself.

The following example makes use of the `Rectangle` class, two of the nice features about this class are...

1. It can paint itself
2. You can use it to determine if a given point is within it's bounds

Which is pretty much all you really want to do

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Rectangle> list = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

        public TestPane() {
            list.add(new Rectangle(20, 20, 20, 20));
            list.add(new Rectangle(40, 40, 20, 20));
            list.add(new Rectangle(60, 60, 20, 20));

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = list.iterator();
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        Rectangle q = iter.next();
                        if (q.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                            iter.remove();
                        }
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (Rectangle rect : list) {
                g2d.fill(rect);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```